# I want to pip install myFile.env

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, miniconda

I have a .env file that I used to create a virtual environment.

I want to install the same packages (as specified in the .env file), but this time 
I dont want it to be a virtual environment. How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Note: 
A .env file can be used by miniconda or anaconda to create virtual environments like so:

```
conda create --name optimus --file alpha.env
```

then you can run

```
source activate optimus
```

to activate your virtualEnv. But how can I do something similar to:

```
pip install -r myFile.env
```

to install all packages specified in myFile.env, but not in a virtual environment.

Here is my alpha.env file:

```
cairo=1.12.2=2
dateutil=2.1=py27_2
freetype=2.4.10=0
numpy=1.6.2=py27.4
```

Comment: What is an `.env` file and what is inside it? Usually `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` are used to create a virtual env.

Comment: Can you paste code in .env file also ?

Comment: Yep, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to your original virtual env or can create a new one as you describe I think a very simple solution would be to simply create a requirements.txt file. This is simply a file that names all the packages that you have installed in a specific python environment.

The file can be created by simply running

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will create a file in your working directory called requirements.txt. You have to have your virtual environment active. To then install the packages in your new environment you just have to enter it (deactivate your virtualenv or what ever you need to do) and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I have never seen a .env file, but by the sound of it it could actually be exactly the same as a requirements.txt file but under a different name. See if the output of 
    pip freeze
looks the same (as far as format etc) as what you have in your .env file. In that case you could also just run the command you would in your virtual env ie.

```
pip install -r myFile.env
```

EDIT:
After seeing your .env file output I am convinced that you can simply run the 
    pip install -r myFile.env
command.